# Regex to match 10-15 digit number

Tags: java, regex

I'm using the below regular expression:

```
 Pattern testPattern= Pattern.compile("^[1-9][0-9]{14}");
 Matcher teststring= testPattern.matcher(number);

if(!teststring.matches())
{
   error("blah blah!");
}
```

My requirements are:

1. To match a 10-15 digit number which should not start with 0 and rest all digits should be numeric.
2. If a 10-15 digit number is entered which starts with zero then teststring does not match with the pattern.my validation error blah blah is displayed.
3. My problem is if I enter 10-15 digit number which does not start with zero then also validation error message gets displayed.

Am I missing anything in regex?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With `"^[1-9][0-9]{14}"` you are matching `15` digit number, and not `10-15` digits. `{14}` quantifier would match exactly `14` repetition of previous pattern. Give a range there using `{m,n}` quantifier:

```
"[1-9][0-9]{9,14}"
```

You don't need to use *anchors* with [`Matcher#matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) method. The anchors are implied. Also here you can directly use [`String#matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) method:

```
if(!teststring.matches("[1-9][0-9]{9,14}")) {
    // blah! blah! blah!
}
```

Answer (score 10):

`/^[1-9][0-9]{9,14}$/` will match any number from 10 to 15 digits.

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/oX7xQ9)

**Autopsy**:

- `^` - this MUST be the start of the text
- `[1-9]` - any digit between 1 and 9
- `[0-9]{9,14}` - any digit between 0 and 9 matched 9 to 14 times
- `$` - this MUST be the end of the text

Answer (score 2):

Or, an alternative so later you have an at-a-glance look -

`^(?!0)\d{10,15}$`

Comment: Surely a negative look-ahead will be much slower?

Comment: Not true. 1 char compare vs. 2 is much faster.

Answer (score 1):

`To match a 10-15 digit number which should not start with 0`

Use end of line anchor `$` in your regex with limit between 9 to 14:

```
Pattern.compile("^[1-9][0-9]{9,14}$");
```